# Javascript - Append a parameter of an option to URL retrieved by a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select

I have a drop down menu. I use it to select a particular Tea.

```
<form name="barcode" onSubmit="return OnSubmitForm();" method="post">

    <select name="entry_id" id="entry_id">
        <option selected="selected">Select a tea</option>
        <td><option entry_id="865"> Black Tea</option></td>
        <td><option entry_id="123"> Green Tea</option></td>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Tea story">
</form>
```

Then I want to use javascript to retrieve `entry_id` of the selected Tea and append the it to end of the URL, e.g. `/myshop/tea/865` <-- 865 is the entry id for Black Tea

My Javascript code:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
    function OnSubmitForm()
    {
        alert('inside');
        var eid = document.getElementById('entry_id').value;
        alert(eid);
        document.barcode.action ="https://www.myshop.ca/tea/" + eid;
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

But every time it append "Black Tea" or "Green Tea" names, e.g, `/myshop/tea/Black Tea` or `/myshop/tea/Green Tea`. Is there a way to append `entry_id` at the end of the URL, e.g. `/myshop/tea/865` or `/myshop/tea/123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="barcode" onSubmit="return OnSubmitForm();" method="post">

    <select name="entry_id" id="entry_id">
       <option selected="selected">Select a tea</option>
       <option value="865">Black Tea</option>
       <option value="123">Green Tea</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Tea story">
    </form>
```

makes more sens. use the form widgets as they are supposed to be used.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.  Thanks for your advice.  I cut and paste form many times.  It mess up the things.  Thanks again.  I will accept your answer and give points.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to have `td`s in a select element. Additionally, you need to set the `value` attribute of the `option` elements to your desired IDs. Eg.:

```
<select name="entry_id" id="entry_id">
   <option selected="selected">Select a tea</option>

   <option value="865"> Black Tea</option>

   <option value="123"> Green Tea</option>
</select>
```